# How to make WCF call from html file?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

i am new to wcf and below is what the WCF WSDL returns, my question is, how to call a WCF service from html page?

```
 <wsdl:definitions name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex">
  - <wsdl:types>
    - <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://..../tools/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://..../tools/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://..../tools/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyService" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like so:

```
        $.ajax({
            url: "/tools/MyService.svc/Getist",
            type: "GET",
            context: document.body,
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                // do something
            }
        });
```

I am not sure about parameters - they will go after Getist in the URL, but I don't know their names - they are stored in /tools/MyService.svc?xsd=xsd0

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a javascript library such as jQuery to make an Ajax request to the web service. I recommend searching google along the lines of "jQuery WCF AJAX" and that should give you some useful examples.